# Can a sample of beta radiation be considered as the fabled philosophers stone?

Tags: radiation, radioactivity

Given that it is possible to [produce gold in nuclear reactors](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-lead-can-be-turned-into-gold/) (even if not economical), is there a natural source of beta radiation whose half life is similar to that of human lifetime and whose beta radiation can induce a change in atomic number in stable elements?

From what I could [find](http://webmineral.com/help/Radioactivity.shtml#Table) in terms of half-life there are none but I thought I'd ask any how, since it is probable.

If there were then it would likely qualify as the philosopher's stone sought out by ancient alchemists is it not?

Comment: I'm puzzled by why you think that betas are a good way to change atomic number.  I'm even more confused by the association of betas with a 'philosophers stone', which has strayed far afield from mainstream physics.

Comment: Given that alchemists preferred their methods *not* to cause severe burns,  you might want to go another route.  </sarcasm>

Comment: Have you asked [Nicholas Flamel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Flamel)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about physics

Comment: @JonCuster Since beta radiation is the result of a change in atomic number, my rationale was that the reverse should be true as well. I did realize that the philosophers stone could possibly be seen as offtopic. However given its properties I would not say it is offtopic for physics. In any case I do believe the examples that I have linked are clearly in the physics domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to do some basic reading about beta decays. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay) at the very least. Beta decay comes in two flavors, + and -. In both cases a neutron decays into a proton and either an electron and an antineutrino or a positron and a neutrino. The emitted electrons/positrons are sometimes called Beta radiation, and I assume this is what you're talking about.

Electrons and positrons are not remotely useful in inducing fission, which would be required to convert lead (atomic number 82) to gold (atomic number 79). Inducing beta decay in lead would also lead in the wrong direction, since converting an neutron to a proton increases the atomic number of a nucleus, rather than decreasing it.

ETA: I misspoke - that is, I was wrong about the details of $\beta$ + decay. Such a process will decrease atomic number by one, so inducing 3 successive instances of $\beta$ + decay would (in theory) produce gold. For about a microsecond.

Lead occurs in 3 isotopes, 206Pb, 207Pb, and 208Pb. A $\beta$ + decay will convert these to thallium, specifically, 206Tl, 207Tl and 208Tl. Each of these isotopes will decay via $\beta$ - decay back to lead with half-lives of 3-4 minutes. But let's say we can induce further $\beta$ + decay and convert the thallium to mercury before the atoms have a chance to decay.

This will produce 206Hg, 207Hg, and 208 Hg. Each of these isotopes will decay via $\beta$ - decay back to thallium, with a half-life  of 3 to 42 minutes. But let's say we again induce $\beta$ + decay, and produce gold, specifically 206Au, 207Au and 208Au.

These gold isotopes will also decay via $\beta$ - decay back to mercury, but the half-life for these isotopes is small but greater than 300 nsec.

And, of course, neither electrons nor positrons will trigger beta decay of either variety, so beta radiation cannot possibly trigger transmutation.

END EDIT

So the simple answer is no.

Equally important is the fact that the Philosopher's Stone had other uses beyond transmutation. The Stone's transformative powers arose from its power to perfect, thereby changing lower "base" (inferior) metals to the more "noble" metals such as silver and gold. As a result, the stone also served as an elixir of life, since it could be used to eliminate imperfections in a person, restoring health and extending lifetime. A body which does not die, of course, is clearly a more perfect body than one which does.

A source of beta radiation is not what you'd call healthy, and $\beta +$ decay produces positrons which annihilate with any nearby electrons to produce high-energy gamma radiation, which is *really* not healthy.

So on this count also, a source of beta radiation is not remotely a Philosopher's Stone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding beta rays being harmful, my point was precisely that as well but my understanding was that if beta decay within a nucleus could alter the atomic number then the converse should be true as well and that the resulting beta particle could either increase or decrease the atomic number of an element that was higher or lower than that of gold. Was I wrong in this understanding ?

Comment: Sorry, but totally wrong. Beta decay can only increase the atomic number of a nucleus, although it might conceivably then fission. If it did, the chances of lead jumping up to bismuth, then splitting into gold and beryllium are infinitesimal. Plus, and I'm repeating myself, there is no such thing as a beta particle. Beta radiation is made up of electrons and positrons, not beta particles or beta rays, and these cannot do what you want.

Comment: As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Beta_decay&oldid=683468487) beta decay can decrease the atomic number (beta+ decay). Refer the nuclear transmutation section in the link. Also by beta-rays/beta-particles I still meant to say beta decay. My question was on the lines of electron capture (as termed in wikipedia), only rather than the proton capturing an electron, my thought was on an incoming beta radiation inducing the change in atomic number. Do you still think all of what I said is incorrect?

Comment: @RavindraHV - My apologies, I had misstated the nature of beta + decay, and have edited my answer. The answer is still no. And electron capture is not an answer in this case. The Wiki article specifically states (when showing examples), "The electron that is captured is one of the atom's own electrons, and not a new, incoming electron". Furthermore, the same article states, "isotopes heavier than the stable ones decay by electron emission.". Since neither thallium nor mercury have stable isotopes greater than 204, neither can be induced to undergo electron capture.

Comment: Are you stating the wiki article in a simplified manner because I was not able to find the same text. Also, while initially my understanding was that the electrons surrounding the atom would impede any interaction between an incoming electron and the nucleus, the equation involving alpha particles and aluminium in the discovery-of-other-types-of-beta-decay section in the wikipedia link would indicate that it may not be that significant.

Comment: Continuing from above comment, I guess effect of bombarding nucleus with electrons is a different topic. I'll flag this as the answer for now. PS : Since this question has a negative score this question will likely be cleaned up but thanks all the same for your inputs.